# summernote rendered in Iron:Router

Tags: meteor, summernote

I use Iron:Router and summernote but it seem not to work properly with each other.
Start with:

```
<div id="summernote"></div>
```

is rendered by

```
Template.newPost.rendered = function(){
$('#summernote').summernote({height: 500});
}
```

Routers are defined

```
Router.route('/home', {name: 'home'});
Router.route('/new-post', {name: 'newPost'})
```

when I switch between 2 templates, this happen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLbCH.png

rendered-summernote keep duplicating between 2 templates
How can this problem be solved?
My Git repo [GitHub](https://github.com/nnquangthang/summernote.git)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Template.newPost.rendered = function(){
    $('#summernote').summernote({height: 500});

}

Template.newPost.events({
   'click #submit': function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     //var title = $('#titleInput').val()
     var content = $('#summernote').code()
     console.log(title);
     var post = {
     //title: title,
     content: content
     };
     console.log(post);
     return false;
   }
 });


Template.newPost.onDestroyed(function() {
    $('#summernote').destroy();
});
```

That's the new-post.js file, it works. What's happening is that on summernote init, the editor replaces the div with id summernote, so it's not really in this template anymore.

Read more: https://atmospherejs.com/summernote/summernote

Comment: How can onDestroyed being used?
div is inside newPost Template

Comment: Right, I guess I know what's the problem, I'll test it and edit my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer, I found a solution. Also created a pull request on github so that you can apply this fix if it works for you

Comment: Thank you so much.
Wish I have enough reputation to upvote you :)
Uh maybe when I have enough it will be displayed

Comment: You're welcome and thank you :) In fact being able to help with Meteor and having your code/fix implemented in someone else's project is so fun and rewarding that you don't really care about points (except for access to more functions on SO etc). Anyway, good luck with your project and if you ever need some help again, I'm here or you can invite me to collab on github. Also, browsing Stack questions and trying to help is great in learning process, it helps me a lot, you should try it too. Cheers!

Comment: Upvote don't cost me anything. It just a little gift to somebody who trying to help :)